# Is there any disadvantages for only using "Child of" modifier instead of parenting the bone in edit mode?

Tags: modifiers, parent

I recently became aware of how the child of modifier is used and it seems to have more customization that basic parenting. is there a disadvantage to just using the modifier (besides not being able to see the relations with the dotted line?)

Comment: It's slower in execution and easier to cause accidental dependency loops -- that can be very hard to debug.  It behaves differently than a connected bone would.

Comment: Yes.  For example, you can't really scale a child-of'd bone or object to a cursor the way you'd expect, because the operation doesn't take into account the child-of.   Child of is useful, but you should stick to regular parenting for typical use.  Other constraints can do what a child-of with options can do better, and the options are almost never a good idea.  Consider also armatures with bones with inherit rotation/inherit scale disabled.

Comment: @Nathan I would upvote this as an answer

Comment: @AllenSimpson It's not really the kind of question I feel like answering, because I can't really give *every* reason, just an example-- so it's not really a complete answer in my mind, you know?  It's just advice, here's one thing that will go wrong, and there are probably more, so don't do it.